# iOS 7 - TabBarController does not have text label

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to create an application with a `UITabBarController`. I have followed several tutorials online and it seems like I'm missing something since my `UITabBarController` does not have text but you can switch from one View to another.

Here is my `didFinishWithLaunchingOptions` function:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
 
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
    ListViewController *listVC = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    self.tabController.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:viewController1, listVC, nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self createCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];

    return YES;
}
```

What am I missing out on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the tab bar image and title of each view controller:

```
self.tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

UIViewController *viewController1 = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
ListViewController *listVC = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

viewController1.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"VC1" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_ yourViewController.png"] tag:0];
listVC.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"listVC" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_listvc.png"] tag:1];

self.tabController.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:viewController1, listVC, nil];
```

It's also possible (and often preferred) to set the tabBarItem for each view controller in `viewDidLoad`, I.e.:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; // Be a good citizen!
    self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init...];
    ...
```

Comment: Personally I think it is better for each view controller to set its own title and image. I do this in the `viewDidLoad` method (or the `init` method) of each view controller. But either way works.

Answer (score 1):

You can set tabbar item for each view with code

```
UITabBar *tabBar = self. tabController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];

[tabBarItem0 setTitle:@"title1"];
[tabBarItem0 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1"]];
[tabBarItem1 setTitle:@"title2"];
[tabBarItem1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2"]];

self.window.rootViewController = self.tabController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```